# python go up 2 directories gives syntax error

Tags: python

I am making a script (python) and need to import other files (complete).
The file I would like to import, is 2 directories up from the script.

Normal in Python you would do something like

```
../../../file.py <-- goes up 3 directories
```

When I do this in Python it gives a syntax error.

`..file` for example works but as soon as I chain it `../..file.py` the syntax error comes in.

I tried 
`../..file` 
`../../file` 
`/../..file` 
`/../../file`

The error says invalid syntax.

The complete command is

```py
from ../..file import *
```

I would like to import all the content of the file.

The path needs to be relative due to the nature of the script. No hardcoding allowed.
How can I go up multiple directories in Python?

Comment: are you talking about relative imports?

Comment: Yes Just updated the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: unfortunately not Though it has some good information :-)

Answer (score 0):

importlib was added to Python 3 to programmatically import a module.

```
import importlib

moduleName = input('Enter module name:')
importlib.import_module(moduleName)
```

The .py extension should be removed from moduleName. The function also defines a package argument for relative imports.

If you want to import the whole file you can just do import file. Then you can choose the function that you are interesting in.
for example:

```
import FULL_PATH_TO_MY_FILE
my_file.my_func...
```

or you can try:

```
from FULL_PATH_TO_MY_FILE import *
```

and then you can use each function in your file like this - `myfunc()`

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. How can I import the whole file content and not only 1 module?

Comment: Import my_file does not seems to work? Sorry for the lack of programming skills

Comment: Does not matter what I do it always errors out see screenshot https://prnt.sc/259fyku

Comment: It needs to be Relative not hardcoded.